# Cannot resolve private void method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android studio does not recognize a method within my code.

I implemented a method to handle the call.

```
private void saveDeal(){
    String title = textTitle.getText().toString();
    String description = textDescription.getText().toString();
    String price = textPrice.getText().toString();

    TravelDeal deal = new TravelDeal(title, description, price, "");
    mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(deal);

}

private void clean(){
    textTitle.setText("");
    textDescription.setText("");
    textPrice.setText("");
    textTitle.requestFocus();
}
```

But in the method call,

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_save:
            saveDeal();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Deal saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            clean();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`saveDeal()` and `clean()` are still showing in red in the `switch` block.

Comment: Are these methods in the same class?

Comment: `Yes. They both belong to the same class.`

Comment: Can you post your whole class code?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. I missed a closing curly bracket in the `switch` statement in the `onOptionsItemsSelectedMenu()` method.

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio Menu, Try `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart`